# Magento backend editor

Tags: php, magento, barcode, magento-1.8

```
<p><barcode code=”{{var ea_invoice_id}}” type=”UPCA” /></p>
```

i am trying to add this on magento back-end editor but while saving it is disappeared. Any solution for this?

Comment: are u sure that there is a tag named with "barcode" in html or html 5???

Comment: no there is no tag but i have to added this code for creating a barcode on invoice

Comment: then this is not the correct way to do that

Comment: any method to add these type of codes

Comment: On which page you are trying to add the barcode?

Comment: i need to add on invoice pdf

Comment: Why does this question get any upvotes?